# c# scope question

Tags: c#, scope

Sorry for the silly question.  I just started C# programming.  I've been researching this for many hours now, and read what I could here.  This is seemingly so common, I just do not understand why it does not work.  I want to declare a variable in a parent method and change the value in a child class.  If this isn't the way to do it, how can I make methods (even for loops or while loops) that return useful data?

Example 1:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int rowID;
        for (int i = 1; i < 500; i++ )
        {
            rowID = i;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(rowID);
    }
```

Example 2:

```
private void SendButtonClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{            
    // finds the first row that has not been sent
    int rowID = GetMessageRow();
    //then process the row and figure out what stored procedure to run 
    RunStoredProcedure(rowID);
}

public int GetMessageRow()
// finds the first row that has not been sent
{
    int rowID;
      // skipping some code
       while (drGetMessageRow.Read())
        {
         // while loop does not understand the variable and errors  
            rowID = drGetMessageRow.GetInt32(0);
            MessageBox.Show("1: RowID is " + rowID.ToString());
        }
}
```

Comment: C# uses *lexical scoping* are opposed to *dynamic scoping*. In short this means a variables scope is directly related to the structure of the code. However, "while loop does not understand the variable" is an incorrect statement. Read the error message again -- what does it say, exactly?

Comment: Where is the variable drGetMessageRow coming from? Is it class level?

Comment: Hmm, I'll add this.  For example 2, it is a try block.  Apparently variables in a try block are scoped.  So the code looks like this:  int rowID; 
 try { 
 /* ... */  
SqlDataReader drGetMessageRow = cmdGetmEssageRow.ExecuteReader;
 while (drGetMessageRow.Read()) {  
   rowID = drGetMessageRow.GetInt32(0); } }

Comment: I figured out I can put everything into a class like so.  class Sproc { public static int rowID = 0;  public int GetMessageRow();  ... public void RunStoredProcedure(int rowID)... }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GetMessageRow method needs to return rowID. This is what allows rowID (which is a different variable) to have its value set in the SendButtonClicked method.

```
public int GetMessageRow()
// finds the first row that has not been sent
{
    int rowID;
    // skipping some code
    while (drGetMessageRow.Read())
    {
        // while loop does not understand the variable and errors  
        rowID = drGetMessageRow.GetInt32(0);
        MessageBox.Show("1: RowID is " + rowID.ToString());
    }

    return rowID;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `return` keyword to return a value from a method.  This keyword exits the method.  Example:

```
 return rowID;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return values. For example, after your `while` loop in `GetMessageRow`, you should 
`return rowID`

Answer (score 1):

To *change* a value (meaning the value *itself*) between methods you start getting into `ref` territory - but I suggest DON'T do that... Yet.

To *return* a useful value just `return` it. One problem with loops in particular is that they might not iterate even once, so in terms of "definite assignment" you often need to assign a default value *outside* the loop.

Another option is to `throw` if you don't get into the loop, or to use LINQ methods like `.First()` or `.Single()`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to run stored procedure for a single rowId that `GetMessageRow` method returns, you need to return the value from your method:

```
public int GetMessageRow()
// finds the first row that has not been sent
{
    int rowID;
      // skipping some code
       while (drGetMessageRow.Read())
        {
         // while loop does not understand the variable and errors  
            rowID = drGetMessageRow.GetInt32(0);
            MessageBox.Show("1: RowID is " + rowID.ToString());
        }

    return rowID;
}
```

If you want to call stored procedure for each row than you need to call `RunStoredProcedure` inside the loop, passing current rowId:

```
public void ProcessMessageRows()
// finds the first row that has not been sent
{
      // skipping some code
       while (drGetMessageRow.Read())
        {
         // while loop does not understand the variable and errors  
            int rowID = drGetMessageRow.GetInt32(0);
            MessageBox.Show("1: RowID is " + rowID.ToString());
            RunStoredProcedure(rowId);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I can put everything into a class like so.

```
class Sproc 
{ 
public static int rowID = 0; 
public int GetMessageRow(); ... 
public void RunStoredProcedure(int rowID)... 
}
```

....  then i can call as follows.

```
    SProc s;
    s = new SProc();

    // finds the first row that has not been sent
    int rowID = s.GetMessageRow();

    //then process the row and figure out what stored procedure to run - this could be (should be) also in the config.
    s.RunStoredProcedure(rowID);
```